# Prevent event overlap in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar, overlap

This is what i want to accomplisch: Events with the same resourceId should not be able to overlap. In this jsbin it works like a charm.
http://jsbin.com/guxeze/2/edit?js,output

But in my live code it doesn't. Is it because i get the events using php? Even when using the setting "eventOverlap: false" it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        //var date = new Date();
        //var d = date.getDate();
        //var m = date.getMonth();
        //var y = date.getFullYear();


        var username = 'api_user';  //api username
        var password = 'api_pass';  //api password

        function make_base_auth(user, password) {
                                                var tok = user + ':' + password;
                                                var hash = btoa(tok);
                                                return "Basic " + hash;
                                                };

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        //Display settings
            //theme: true,
            //aspectRatio: 1, // Width / height ratio. By default this is 1.35
            header: {
                    left: 'prev,next, today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaThreeDay,agendaDay' //ook mogelijk basicWeek, basicDay
                    },
            firstDay: 1, //Sunday=0, Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc.
            //hiddenDays: [ 0 ], //hide sunday [ 1, 3, 5 ] // hide Mondays, Wednesdays, and Fridays
            weekNumbers: true,
            businessHours: {
                            start: '7:00',  // a start time
                            end: '19:00',   // an end time
                            dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
                            // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
                            // (Monday-saturday in this example)
                            },
            views: {
                    agendaFourDay: {
                                    type: 'agenda',
                                    duration: { days: 4 },
                                    buttonText: '4 Dagen'
                                    },
                    agendaThreeDay: {
                                    type: 'agenda',
                                    duration: { days: 3 },
                                    buttonText: '3 dagen'
                                    }
                    },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',  // default view to open calendar month,agendaWeek,agendaThreeDay,agendaDay
            timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',       // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
            lang: 'nl',

        //Calendar settings
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,   //allow "more" link when too many events

        // Prevent overlap of events with the same instructorId 
            eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
                                                            return stillEvent.instructorId != movingEvent.instructorId;
                                                            },

        //Events
            events: {
                    url:'events.php',
                    error: function() {
                                        alert('Er heeft zicht een fout voorgedaan bij het ophalen van de afspraken! Controleer de event settings, database connectie en events.php');
                                        },
                    },




    });
```

It definitly seems to be a problem with the php:
When adding events as code instead of using php it does work.

But then again it should work like it does works in this example:
http://jsbin.com/decuda/1/edit?js,output

Comment: What do you have in both instructorId? And how are they assigned? (I couldn't find anything in the documentation)

Comment: instructorId is a custom field I added to the database. It contains some characters, when the same they shouldn't be able to overlap.
When using a standard field like "resourceId" it does not work either

Comment: From what I see, the check is case sensitive, have you tried to make sure your characters are absolutely identical, e.g:
`return stillEvent.instructorId.toUpperCase() != movingEvent.instructorId.toUpperCase();`

Comment: @Slyvain : I tried this, but it did nog solve the problem. I dont think the problem is in this part of the code. 
When I just use "eventOverlap: false" it doesnt work either.

Comment: Ok, just eliminating the obvious sources of issues. I have been toying with the two JSBin you provided, and the function works all the time, whether the events are loaded from another file or hard-coded. Now the only thing left that might be a problem I can think of is what your `events.php` returns. Could you provide the code and json it generates?

Comment: You need to do some debugging work on your end because we can't play with it. Use `console.log(stillEvent, movingEvent)` inside `eventOverlap` and make sure the `instuctorId` is being retrieved from the DB correctly.

Comment: @Slyvain : when cleaning up my php-code to put it online I found a piece of code that was not working like it should. And that was the reason why it was not working. The following code puts wrong data in my json. And this overrides the setting in fullcalendar.
if ($row['overlap'] == "false"){$eventsArray['overlap'] = false;}
    else{$eventsArray['overlap'] = true;};

Comment: Glad you found it! ;)